# Application Auto-closes after dialog box

Tags: vb.net, winforms, visual-studio-2013

New to VB.NET but pretty stumpped at the moment.

My Windows Form application launches 'Form1' which then starts a dialog box using:

`Dim dialogResult As Boolean = configWizard.ShowDialog()`

The ConfigWizard then writes some data to the registry, pops up with the new registry values and closes at which point the rest for Form1 loads.
This all works fine.. When debugging from Visual Studio 2015.

The problem I'm facing is when I build an installer for this program using the in-built InstallShield. The installer set the registry values on install (which works perfectly) then the dialog box opens, sets new values and pops up with the new values it's written. This all works fine. However, the Form1 closes straight away as soon as I press 'OK' on the dialog box.
It's supposed to pop up with a message box saying 'True' but the entire program closes.

Upon constant running of the program it did appear that the Form1 did flash up for milliseconds before disappearing. Does seem like the program is just closing for some unknown reason. I'm pretty stumped as to how to stop the Form1 from closing. Any light of questions to help out would be must appreciated.

I've omitted some code that is irrelivent.
I managed to quick take a screenshot when the Form1 did flash up (verifying both Form1 and the messagebox saying 'True' ARE loading after the dialogbox is closing.. albeit only for a split second)

Code:

**Dialog Box:**

    `Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click`

```
    myValue1= Me.myValue1.Text
    myValue2= Me.myValue2.Text

    Dim regKey As RegistryKey
    regKey = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("SOFTWARE\removedSoftware", True)

    regKey.SetValue("value1", myValue1)
    regKey.SetValue("value2", myValue2)
    MsgBox(myValue1 & " + " & myValue2)
    MsgBox("Registry: " & regKey.GetValue("value1") & " data: " & regKey.GetValue("value2"))
    regKey.Close()

    Me.Close()
End Sub
```

**Form1**

`Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Dim dialogResult As Boolean = configWizard.ShowDialog()
        Try
        Catch ex As Exception
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString)
        End Try
        MsgBox(dialogResult)
End Sub`

Comment: The screenshot is here: http://s8.postimg.org/tmyekgmet/flash1.png

Comment: Start moving the call to ShowDialog inside the ty/catch block. Is this a 64bit application?

Comment: Thanks for replying; No it's a 32bit application (The TargetCPU is AnyCPU but is ticked "prefer 32-bit. I need it to run on both 32bit and 64bit) Adding the showdialog into the Try/Catch block doesn't change anything.

Comment: Can you show a code where `Form1` was instantiated and shown? Also did set somewhere in the Form1 code `Me.DialogResult` property with some value?

Comment: Of course, all code can be viewed here: http://pastebin.com/Gmm9v7UN .. I have taken out a lot of code to do with DataGridView simply to cut out clutter. I would like to reiterate, when debugging the program, it works fine. When running the standalone .exe in the Debug directory, it works fine. It only shuts down after the dialog box when it's fully installed via InstallShield. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use OnShown event (`Form1_Shown`) instead of OnLoad to display the dialog box.

Comment: Thanks for reply; I have changed it so all data being loaded is fired on Form1_Shown  instead on OnLoad. However, although Form1 loads before the dialog box, when the dialog is closed, it still closes the entire application.